# Batch reading dir and file problem

Tags: batch-file

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b C\logs\*.log') do (
 for /f "tokens=2,3,4 " %%i in (\\***%%f) do (
  if %%i==START echo %%k
 )
)
```

this script wil brouwse all *.log files searching for START as a second word en then wil echo me the fourth word (a time stamp) but i want that time stamp in a var like this but i doesnt work

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b C\logs\*.log') do (
 for /f "tokens=2,3,4 " %%i in (\\***\%%f) do (
  if %%i==START set timestamp=%%k
 )
 echo %timestamp%
)
```

the %timestamp% var is empty when i echo it? can somebody help me?

Regard Marco

Comment: Install cygwin, then run a bash script.

Comment: @LatinSuD it is aa .bat batch script witch is the native commandline tool for windows xp so why should i use cygwin to "emulate" linux api's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying a variable inside a loop, so you have to add this line to the beginnig of your code:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

you also have to change the

```
echo %timestamp%
```

to

```
echo !timestamp!
```